# Is there in signal processing similar method than Otsu's method in image processing?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, signal-detection

I'm just wondering that is there any similar method for separate signal and signal+noise in signal processing like otsu's method set threshold to valley of image histogram? And if there is how can I implement it in Matlab.

Comment: you are basically looking for a 2 class classifier? Yes, lots of ways to do that. How about Fisher discriminant analysis? or linear discriminant analysis?